# Blender to Unity object position issue

Tags: export, transforms, unity

Blender export settings

[image: upload_2023-3-12_17-14-21.png]

Shadergraph
[image: upload_2023-3-12_17-15-31.png]

Working Case : when object size is withint 2,2,2, world origin is 0,0,0, object pivot is middle (1,1,1)

[image]

Not working when...

1. the object size exceed 2x2x2, same position with the image above, scale :1

[image]

2. when object origin is on its feet (bottom)
   [image]

Expected result :
Color lerping between top and bottom of the object based on the object's height no matter how big is and when its exported position is like the last picture (origin is its feet where 0,0,0 in my blender scene)

Hi,

I'm having an issue with my shader using object position. basically lerping two colours based on object Y axis.

My expected result is having two colours blendeing between top to bottom of an object no matter how how big or small its size is. and preferably the objects should have pivot at theirs feet (0,0,0)

I assume the object space in my shadergraph only count 1x1x1 and anything exceeding this area will have the sharp dividing line. wonder if there's any way I can set them as literally object size (scale 1)?

Any input from you would be very helpful Thanks. Cheers!